# How to execute the Node JS scheduler within the express JS in Kubernetes cluster environment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I am running Node JS with Express JS in Kubernetes cluster as service using Deployment YML file with 2 replicas. I am using HELM for deployment.

Now I am having the requirement to execute the scheduler to run a particular task at a given interval.

If I am running it as single instance, I can implement within the same service, but since I am using replicas, the scheduler will be run in two different pods at same time.

Is there a way to configure such that I can run the scheduler in a single pod and disable it in another pod of the same Node JS service?

Or do I want to move as a separate Node JS service and maintain it?

Can you please provide your suggestion?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: I am using version v1.22.4

Comment: Do you want to run your custom scheduler or do you want to run only some task in Kubernetes?

Comment: I want to run the custom scheduler that performs some tasks in intervals of time.

Comment: Why do you not want to use CronJob to run your tasks?

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes, you can find an Object named [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).

This will achieve a scheduler role, as a Linux cron would.

You can use the same image as your express JS app, but start a different script that will exit with a code at the end.

Example:

`node app.js` starts your express server

`node schedule.js` starts your cron task

Best,